# Does Anaconda download packages every-time you install them in a new conda environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

If I make a new conda environment and for example, then use the command

```
pip install numpy
```

Considering I have the `numpy` module installed in the conda base environment, will the above command to install numpy re-download the `numpy` packages from the internet or just use the ones from the base environment?

Comment: yes it will, every conda env is independent from the other

Comment: "*re-download the numpy packages from the internet or just use the ones from the base environment?*" Neither. `pip` has caching so the package will not be downloaded, it will be installed from the cache, but it will be installed into the new environment.

Comment: Okay so what I'm observing is - when I'm trying to install numpy into a new conda environment using the above mentioned command, it is not working if I switch off the internet connection and is working perfectly fine when my internet is connected. Ps: I already have numpy library installed into my base conda environment.  What might be going on here ?

Comment: `pip` checks for a newer version at PyPI before using cache.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. Thanks alot @phd